# Error importing MySQL database using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am importing a MySQL database from another server to my own server using phpMyAdmin. But the problem is:

*I go into import then choose a file which have extension like `.sql`, `.xml`. After this procedure I click on the **ok** button but this doesn't give any response and doesn't even do anything, the page just remains stable.*

I also tried with **MySQL command prompt** using `mysqldump`.

```
mysqldump -u username -p databse > database name
```

but this is also giving an error.

Can any one please help me in solving this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This command is used to export :

`mysqldump -h hostname -u username -p database > sql_file_name`

to import you should use

`mysql -h hostname -u username -p database < full_file_path`

Comment: i have tried to export my database name "test" but it's gives error. that command i used is: "mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p test > test_db;"

Comment: You should use as : `mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p test > test_db.sql`

Comment: not running both of commands. never exporting neither importing

Answer (score -1):

first you need to export a DB from the first server.
on your server you first need to create a new DB and than do the import.
the DB you imported will go to the DB you just created.

Comment: according to you i created a new database **newExport** after that in _> import > choose database_. but page does't gives any response.